# Using SCP function from Rcurl in R

Tags: r, ssh

I have tested my SSH authentication using `PuTTY` with success, which I mean I can `ssh` to remote server using the private key provided. However, I am trying to use `SCP` function from `Rcurl` package in R, I got the error message saying:

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Authentication failure

Here is my code

```
r <- scp(host='eee.com', path = "/aaa/bbb/test.sas7bdat", 
         keypasswd = NA, user = "yyyyyy", rsa = TRUE, 
         key = "C:/Users/.ssh/authorized_keys", binary = NA)
```

`C:/Users/.ssh/authorized_keys` is my private RSA key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that "key" must contain both the public and the private key. This should work:

```
r <- scp(host='eee.com', path = "/aaa/bbb/test.sas7bdat", keypasswd = NA, user = "yyyyyy", rsa = TRUE, key = c("C:/Users/.ssh/authorized_keys.pub","C:/Users/.ssh/authorized_keys"), binary = NA)
```

Comment: any pointers how to do this on a linux machine? I have added my public key to ~/.ssh/ as id_rsa.pub (I tried the open-ssh and secure shell format) in addition to the id_rsa private key.  I still run into ` Failure establishing ssh session: -5, Unable to exchange encryption keys`  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and did not get `scp` to work, but found a workaround in `getURLContent`:

```
x <- getURLContent("sftp://path/file", .opts = list( 
       ssh.private.keyfile = "path/keyfile",
       username="username",
       keypasswd="password"))
```

And the private key should be an openSSH key (I had to convert my puttygen key) and while I had to download binary content I used `getBinaryURL` in the end with the same arguments.