# RCurl::scp() - Unable to exchange encryption keys

Tags: r, ssh, libcurl, scp, rcurl

I currently try to read a file from a remote machine via `RCurl::scp()` on linux.

I have added my public (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in open-ssh format) and private (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) keys and am able to ssh and scp to the remote machine from the terminal.

Unfortunatley I cannot yet transfer or read a file from within R.

```
RCurl::scp(
  user = "root", host = "hostname",
  path = "/path/file",
)
#> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#>   Failure establishing ssh session: -5, Unable to exchange encryption keys
```

My question may be related to [Using SCP function from Rcurl in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313391/using-scp-function-from-rcurl-in-r)